# How to negate code in "if" statement block in JavaScript -JQuery like 'if not then..'

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, conditional-statements

For example if I want to do something if parent element for **used** element hasn't got `ul` tag as next element, how can I achieve this?

I try some combination of `.not()` and/or
`.is()` with no success.

What's the best method for negate code of a `if else` block?

**My Code**

```
if ($(this).parent().next().is('ul')){
   // code...
}
```

**I want to achieve this**

Pseudo Code:

```
if ($(this).parent().next().is NOT ('ul')) {
    //Do this..
}
```

Comment: You can take the jQuery out of this question.

Comment: When you say next do you really mean next, as in the parent's sibling, or do you mean something else?

Comment: @Tomalak - The only justification for the tag is that including it helps to set the context for his question...

Comment: @Justin: You might as well tag it `ul` and `DOM`, too.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You can use the Logical NOT `!` operator:

```
if (!$(this).parent().next().is('ul')){
```

Or equivalently (see comments below):

```
if (! ($(this).parent().next().is('ul'))){
```

For more information, see the [Logical Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) section of the MDN docs.

Answer (score 6):

Try negation operator `!` before `$(this)`:

```
if (!$(this).parent().next().is('ul')){
```