# If ("!" BooleanFunction())

Tags: javascript, if-statement, boolean-logic

Suppose that you have a `function booleanFunction(param)` that sometimes it returns `true` and sometimes it returns `false`.

How does the following condition works?

```js
if (! booleanFunction(param)){
  ...
}
```

Comment: [How to negate code in “if” statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684051/how-to-negate-code-in-if-statement)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It calls the function, and then applies the negation operator (`!`) to the result the function returns. So if the function returns `true`, the condition is false (`!true` is `false`); if the function returns `false`, the condition is true (`!false` is `true`). (As a side-effect, it will also coerce *truthy* and *falsy* values to `false` or `true`, respectively. (*Falsy* values are `0`, `""`, `NaN`, `undefined`, `null`, and of course `false`; *truthy* values are everything else.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So, it will enter in the if only if the function returns false (i.e., it will enter in the if only if the condition in it is true)?

Comment: @ActuallyLZ: Exactly (well, if the function returns any *falsy* value, the condition will be `true` and the body of the `if` will be executed).

Answer (score 0):

The not operator:

- Implicitly converts whatever is on the RHS to a boolean
- Inverts it (converting `true` to `false` or vice versa)

The `if` statement then tests to see if that inverted value is `true` or `false` and either does or does not run the following block of code.